# Images.xcassets in Xcode 6

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, xcasset, launchimage

I am trying to figure out how to use the xcassets folder in Xcode 6 and I have to say Apple could have done a way better job. I'm a big fan of Xcode but their images storage per type of screen / phone is a nightmare.

First, in my application I am using images which will have a height of half their width. From what I understood, taking pictures of around 1200x600px should do for all types of iphones (full width minus small margin). So I put them in 3x universal, right? If I gave the maximum size why would apple need 1x and 2x ...? Just resize it yourself, no? Is it compulsory for me to give something or will it work by itself? Images are not vector but simple PNGs. In the simulator nothing is complaining and it works well for all types of iphones. Is it okay to leave the other two empty? From I see from the simulator iphone 6 will use downsized @3x images so what is the point of having two images? Only ratio is important and they have the same ...

Secondly, I just added today a launch screen for retina hd 5.5 / 4.7 and now when I run the app in the simulator my uitableviews only take around 4/5 of the full width instead of full width .... can't figure out why adding a launch screen would modify layout of my uitableviews ....? Navigation bar and other screens seem untouched though ...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For part 2 I was using self.frame.size.width in a custom uitableviewcell which made it stuck at 320 pt. Now I am using [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] to get proper width for my cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need  to add the images for the 2x & 3x because when you add large size image then at the run time this image get resize as per the actual width of the image it utilize memory lots of memory to do this & some time if your application have too many images then you will get memory issues

if you want to test this then run your application in iPhone 5 then see the memory utilisation by first keeping the high resolution image now take image which will be of appropriate size to iPhone 5 & then run again you will see the difference

so the best practice is to use different image for different size & not images in this fashion.

The answer to your second Question
if you are not adding the splash screen for iPhone 6/6+ then iOS stretches your UI of iphone 5 to fit into the size of the iPhone 6/6+.
But when you add splash screen it stops doing that.

Comment: I'll give it a try for 2x and 3x images. Regarding second question, what is the difference between using dynamic sizes that work for iphone 6 and 5 and using fixed sizes that works for 320 points wide and let iphone scale up automatically?

Comment: by not using iPhone 6 / 6+ splash screen that indicates you are not giving the support for them & when you open app in App Store in the compatibility section their will only be iPhone 5s no iphone6/6+ . other thing is you will not have full control of you app in iphone6/6+ you will have to rely on scale up only

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but yes you need to manage all this resolution by yourself. Otherwise it will consume more memory.

but yes there is one tool which will make your work less by generating all assets for you

[image] [AVXCassets Generator](https://github.com/angelvasa/AVXCAssets-Generator)